# Accessing private members c++

Tags: c++, private

In this code why can I access the private member of the object with no compiler error?

```
class Cents
{
private:
    int m_nCents;
public:
    Cents(int nCents=0)
    {
        m_nCents = nCents;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    Cents(const Cents &cSource)
    {
        m_nCents = cSource.m_nCents;
    }

    Cents& operator= (const Cents &cSource);

};

Cents& Cents::operator= (const Cents &cSource)
{
```

cSource.m_nCents is private why can I do the following:

```
    m_nCents = cSource.m_nCents;

    // return the existing object
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: If it is like Java, it is because instances of the same class can access other instances' fields without problem. Fields are private to the class, not to instances.

Comment: Are you very new to object oriented paradigm?

Comment: If a class couldn't access its own private member variables, who could?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `private` means "<s>visible</s> accessible to the class", not "<s>visible</s> accessible to the object".

Comment: Visibility is one thing, and accessibility is another. Private members are visible even outside the class, to non-member functions, but they are inaccessible.

Answer (score 4):

You can access private members from member-functions/constructors/destructor/freinds of the class. It is class-based accessibility, not object-based accessibility.